# HTML picture always loads fallback on iOS browsers

Tags: html, ios, image, webp, mobile-browser

I'm using a picture element to render WebP versions of images with the option to fallback to the unmodified JPEG if the browser does not support WebP. On Chrome and Safari on iOS, network requests are made for both versions of the image, webp and jpeg, even though it should be able to render webp on the recent browser versions.

It's difficult to troubleshoot without using a service like LambdaTest that lets you open dev tools on a mobile device, but that was how I found it after noticing poor mobile performance. Another possibly relevant detail is that it loads all JPEGs immediately, when they should lazy load. If there are 10 images on a page and 3 are above the fold, network requests will show all 10 jpegs loaded and only 3 webp images loaded, instead of 3 of each. I haven't been able to find any similar issues, so maybe I'm doing something very basic wrong.

This is what I currently have.

```
<picture>
  <source srcSet="image.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <img src="original-image.jpg" alt="image" />
</picture>
```

I've also tried adding the original image as a second source, since I've seen some examples done that way, but it didn't help.

This all works exactly as I expect on desktop browsers. The WebP images are the only ones that load, according to dev tools. No issues on Android browsers either.